# Blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. How to fix

Tags: ajax, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to hit an API from the browser using a AJAX call, and I see this inside my browser.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://.......us-east-1.amazonaws.com/...' from origin 'https://....cloudfront.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The back-end was an actually a AWS lambda. So should I fix this on the client side or the server side?

Comment: This AWS doc may provide answers to your CORS questions in this context: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Comment: it should be fixed *"on the requested resource"*

Answer (score 0):

Set headers to your LAMBDA response.

```
var response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
};
```

You can set `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` specific headers you want to allow instead of `*` (ALL) and domain also.